# Caffe - Concat layer input and output

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I read about Concat layer on Caffe [website](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers/concat.html). However, I don't know if my understanding of it is right.

Let's say that as an input I have two layers that can be described as **W1 x H1 x D1** and **W2 x H2 x D2**, where **W** is the width, **H** is height and **D** is depth.

Thus, as I understand with Axis set to **0** output will be **(W1 + W2) x (H1 + H2) x D, where D = D1 = D2**.

With Axis set to **1** output will be **W x H x (D1 + D2)**, where **H = H1 = H2** and **W = W1 = W2**.

Is my understanding correct? If no I would be grateful for an explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid you are a bit off...
Look at [this caffe.help](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/concat.html).

Usually, data in caffe is stored in **4**D "blobs": `B`x`C`x`H`x`W` (that is, batch size by channel/feature/depth by height by width).
Now if you have two blobs `B1`x`C1`x`H1`x`W1` and `B2`x`C2`x`H2`x`W2` you can concatenate them along `axis: 1` (along channel dimension) to form an output blob with `C=C1+C2`. This is only possible iff `B1==B2` and `H1==H2` and `W1==W2`, resulting with `B1`x`(C1+C2)`x`H1`x`W1`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I understand correctly Batch size is only a parameter that decides about how many images are sent to GPU (or CPU) at once. Thus, if I set batch_size to 1, then I can just look at what Concat layer does with 2 images. And then, what I wrote about output with Axis set to 1 is correct. Right?

Comment: @AleksanderMonk even when your `batch_size: 1` you have a 4D blob with `B=1`. Note that the order of the dimensions in caffe is different than what you wrote in your question